# How to find out file details behind url?

Tags: php, file, url

I have URL:

https://jumbo-beta.iskon.hr/dl/6c6e4510-765b-401f-9793-f98a8e6e941b

And i want to find out file details behind that URL. (Filname, size, etc.) I don't want to download the file, just find details.

Can this be done with php?

Thx

Comment: Discover [`get_headers()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have the power for do that!.

I think the best approach is getting it from HTTP headers, and another approach is downloading at temporary directory and extracting information from it.

Edit 
Example

```
<?php

$headers = get_headers("https://jumbo-beta.iskon.hr/dl/6c6e4510-765b-401f-9793-f98a8e6e941b");
preg_match_all("/(?P<key>([\w-]+)):(\s+)?(?P<value>(.+))/", implode("\r\n", $headers), $matches);

$values = array_combine($matches['key'], $matches['value']);
preg_match('/filename="(?P<name>(.+))"/', $values['Content-Disposition'], $file);

$content_type = $values['Content-Type'];
$filesize     = $values['Content-Length'];
$filename     = $file['name'];

var_dump($content_type, $filesize, $filename);
```

And then you can access all ...

The output of following code ...

```
string 'image/jpeg; charset=ISO-8859-2' (length=31)
string '130677' (length=7)
string 'WWW.YIFY-TORRENTS.COM.jpg' (length=25)
```

Comment: how about proving some code at least

Comment: Hi, i tryed with HTTP headers, but it didn't work for me. (Don't know hat I did wrong). This works. Thanx.

Sorry for not posting any code, but I tought that question was so trivial (and it was).

Answer (score 0):

`get_headers` WILL download the entire file before returning, because it uses a `GET` request.

Before calling `get_headers`, use the following:

```
stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => 'HEAD')));
```

Comment: When I add this before calling get_header i don't get full info.

Printing $content_type, $filesize , and $filename i get:
text/plain; charset=UTF-8
130677

Answer (score 0):

YES, in PHP there is a lot of functions that Return information about a file

[finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) -- finfo::file — Return information about a file

Also there is too many functions on images processing:
[exif_read_data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) can help you!

```
<?php
$exif = exif_read_data("https://jumbo-beta.iskon.hr/dl/6c6e4510-765b-401f-9793-f98a8e6e941b", 0, true);
echo "test.jpg:<br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

output :

> test.jpg:
>
> FILE.FileName: 6c6e4510-765b-401f-9793-f98a8e6e941b
>
> FILE.FileDateTime: 0
>
> FILE.FileSize: 130677
>
> FILE.FileType: 2
>
> FILE.MimeType: image/jpeg
>
> FILE.SectionsFound:
>
> COMPUTED.html: width="350" height="500"
>
> COMPUTED.Height: 500
>
> COMPUTED.Width: 350
>
> COMPUTED.IsColor: 1

Comment: FILE.FileName: 6c6e4510-765b-401f-9793-f98a8e6e941b

This is not correct filename.